# Allow to find only users members of a specific group in 1 query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build a query that returns all users that match a criteria (UPN starts with "AAD") AND that are members of a specific AAD group. For example:

```
/users?$filter=(startswith(UserPrincipalName, 'aad') and memberOf eq 'GroupID')
```

But that doesn't work. Graph explorer returns error "Invalid filter clause" for both 1.0/Beta versions.
I know I can split it:

1. Get all users that match my criteria (for example UPN starts with "AAD")
2. For each user returned, check if he is member of the AAD group.

But this means that for each user returned, 1 additional query must be done, it's very not optimized.

Is such query possible in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot filter against two directory objects like this (i.e. filter `users` *and* `groups`). You need to pull down the data and do one of the two on the client.

With this in mind, you are better off flipping this query around. Instead of pulling users that start with "aad", pull all the members of the Group and parse the `userPrincipalName` on the client:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members?$select=userPrincipalName
```